# TDS not able to locate Visual Studio

Tags: tds

I am trying to install TDS 6.0.018, I already installed Visual Studio 2019 Professional, but it is giving below error

[image]

If any one faced this issue, please suggest a fix

Comment: When you installed TDS, did it show vs 2019 option?

Comment: No, now the installer comes with only SitecoreTDS msi file

Comment: Try stopping VS2019 first and then install it.

Comment: Try to close VS and try

Comment: I closed VS and tried but it did not worked

Comment: do you have any TDS version installed before as well?

Comment: I am setting this on a new machine